# Android Crop loads wrong image

Tags: android, image, crop

I have a problem with basic android cropping. When I start the activity, it loads same image that has been used long time ago but not an actual image. 
Anyone knows that error?

This is my code:

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

cropIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)), "image/*");

cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);

cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_CODE);
```

In imagePath is path of actual image on SD card. But in the cropping activity there is another image.